# Will the laptop trigger critical battery action if I set critical battery to 0%?

Tags: laptop, battery-life, battery

If I set critical battery to 0%, does it mean that even if I have Hibernate on critical battery, the laptop will simply ignore it (since at 0% it is does not even have the power required to do a hibernate anymore)?

Or is it true that no matter how low I've set that number for critical battery (even 0%), the laptop will still try to run the *mode* I've set on critical battery (currently set to Hibernate that is), and thus will attempt to Hibernate (save my stuff) before actually power-dead?

Note that I'm aware at times due to sufficiently low power, the computer can "try" to Hibernate but will fail halfway (leaving things in a GG state), I'm simply wondering if I have critical battery set to 0% it will even "try" to Hibernate).

[image]

Comment: What?!  Setting critical battery level on 0%?!  Please... please don't try this out - this is MADNESS!

Comment: Is this Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In this case, zero doesn't mean it is dead.  Zero means whatever the battery tell the OS.  I've done this before and usually Windows will hibernate your computer before you get to the critical level.

I don't see the point of setting to zero.

Comment: well if i set to zero i can be able to squeeze maybe 3 more minutes of usage before my battery dies out

Comment: You realize that that absolutely wrecks havoc on your batteries total cycle lifetime. . .

Comment: but how, or why is it so? i'm really nt aware of it.

Comment: There are like 1000 battery life cycle articles out there. All I know is people who know far more calculus than is humanly possible have said so.  So I listen to them. . .

Comment: what had  calculus gotta do with this?!

Comment: This did not work to me - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes this will work

However it is a little pointless, you'll only be getting a few minutes more of battery. The only way I can see this being possible is if you wanted to destroy your battery and have just enough time to shutdown your computer. It would be much more reasonable to set it to 5%, that way you aren't killing your battery (by killing I mean chemically destroying it). The point of setting a critical battery level in your operating systems interface is to make sure that your computer turns off by itself, not because it is out of juice. If you are that desperate for battery, you should consider taking a charger with you in your backpack, laptops don't typically take that long to charge.